# How to join firebaseArray in angular Controller

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have two database structure
One is for keeping Book Concept Name

```
Concept
  |
   Chapter ID
       |
        Concept Id1
           |
             Concept Name: Concept 1
       |
       Concept Id2
           |
             Concept Name: Concept 2
```

Another database structure is for content description of Book Concepts It looks like this

```
Contents
     |
      Chapter Id
         |
         Concept Id1
               |
               Page Id1
                  |
                   PageNo:1
                   Text: this is page 1
                |
                Page Id2
                   |
                   PageNo:2
                   Text: This is page 2
            |
            Concept Id2
                Page Id3
                  |
                   PageNo:1
                   Text: this is page 1
```

In my angular Controller I am fetching concepts like this to be displayed on the HTML page:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/concepts/"+chapterId);
$scope.concepts = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

I am fetching $scope.concepts in HTML through ng-repeat like this:

```
 <li ng-repeat="(id,concept) in concepts">

    <div class="row">

    <h3 ng-model="concept.conceptname">{{concept.conceptname}}</h3>

  </div>
```

Now I want to show How many pages each concept have and want to display that number within the Concept Name.

I am fetching the pages through firebase query:

```
 var refPage=new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/contents/"+chapterId+"/"+$scope.conceptId);
$scope.count=$firebaseArray(refPage);
```

I am displaying this count on same concept HTML page like this:

```
 <li ng-repeat="(id,concept) in concepts">

    <div class="row">

    <h3 ng-model="concept.conceptname">{{concept.conceptname}}</h3>

  </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="row" ng-repeat="count in count">

      <a ng-href="#/some URL/" target="_blank">Page {{count.PageNo}}</a>
      </div>
```

This always returns the no. of pages of last child and shows the same count for every concept.
I want it to display 2 pages for Concept 1 and 1 page for Concept 2 . But it shows always 1 page for each concept.
Is there any way to fetch the respective pages for corresponding Concept ID.

I tried using Firebase.util.NormalizedCollection also but it didnt work. May be I am doing it wrong.
Any help how to achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: You should use $firebaseObject(); ....